# Can I add a hook in openbox

Tags: openbox, hook

The idea is to set per application keyboard shortcut. A hook after that application window get focus and before it's lost focus is needed to switch the keybinding.
This question is related to 
https://superuser.com/questions/993950/how-do-i-make-emacs-key-bindings-work-everywhere-in-linux